# Access iFrame from vba correctly

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am trying to get the product description field from amazon.

For example: `http://www.amazon.com/GMC-Denali-Black-22-5-Inch-Medium/dp/B00FNVBS5C/ref=sr_1_1?s=outdoor-recreation&ie=UTF8&qid=1436768082&sr=1-1&keywords=bicycle`

This is my code:

```
Sub ScrapeProductDesc()

 Dim Ie As New InternetExplorer
 Dim WebURL
 Dim Docx As HTMLDocument
 Dim productDesc
 Dim RcdNum


Ie.Visible = False

For RcdNum = 2 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

WebURL = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A" & RcdNum)
 Ie.Navigate2 WebURL
 Do Until Ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
 DoEvents
 Loop
 Set Docx = Ie.document
 productTitle = Docx.getElementById("productTitle").innerText

 '####### Product Desc
 productDesc = Ie.document.Window.frames("product-description-iframe").contentWindow.document.getElementsByClassName("productDescriptionWrapper").innerText

 'print to workbook
 ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A" & RcdNum) = productDesc
 Next

End Sub
```

As the product description is in an IFrame I am doing: `productDesc = Ie.document.Window.frames("product-description-iframe").contentWindow.document.getElementsByClassName("productDescriptionWrapper").innerText`

However, I get the error message: `Object does not support this property or method.` for this line.

I guess accessing the iFrame is not correct.

Any suggestion how to access the iframe correctly?

Comment: split that line in many, using intermediate variables, so you can locate the bug more precisely :)

Comment: or you could add watch for "Ie.document", then try to expand all nodes in your long expression

Comment: @paulbica I tried this, but I get the error `Out of memory`, when looking at the code.

Comment: @franciscod I would appreciate your answer on how to specifically split up my statement?

Answer (score 1):

Try declaring a variable as As MSHTML.HTMLWindow2 and setting it equal to Docx.frames(0)

```
Sub ScrapeProductDesc()

 Dim Ie As New InternetExplorer
 Dim WebURL
 Dim Docx As HTMLDocument
 Dim productDesc
 Dim RcdNum
 Dim prdt As MSHTML.HTMLWindow2



Ie.Visible = False

For RcdNum = 2 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

WebURL = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A" & RcdNum)
 Ie.Navigate2 WebURL
 Do Until Ie.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
 DoEvents
 Loop
 Set Docx = Ie.Document
 Set prdt = Docx.frames(0)
 productTitle = prdt.Document.getElementById("productTitle").innerText

 '####### Product Desc
 productDesc = prdt.Document.getElementsByClassName("productDescriptionWrapper")(0).innerText

 'print to workbook
 ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A" & RcdNum) = productDesc
 Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thx for your answer! Would you be so kind to show this as an vba example?

Comment: Edited to include the VBA.  However, I can't test it since you didn't include the actual URL as you have it on the worksheet.  Your line to get the productdesc will also cause an error in your original code.  "getelementsbyclassname" returns a collection of elements, not just one.  Therefore you need to specify the index number as well

Comment: Thx for your answer! I have pasted the actual url in the firs sheet on `A2`

Comment: No, I get the error: `Access is denied` at this line: `productDesc = prdt.document.getElementsByClassName("productDescriptionWrapper")(0).innerText`